# How get a current position of textBox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

How can I get a current position of textBox element when call this method?

```
 private void UserTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

**UPDATE**

```
 GeneralTransform gt = this.TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual as UIElement);
            Point offset = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
            double controlTop = offset.Y;
            double controlLeft = offset.X;
```

When I use this controlTop and controlLeft are (0,0)

Answer (score 1):

Because the "this" in your update is the page object. Name your textbox with x:Name="MyTextbox" in your xaml. Then in your focus event handler:

```
private void UserTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GeneralTransform gt = MyTextbox.TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual);
    Point offset = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
    double controlTop = offset.Y;
    double controlLeft = offset.X;
}
```

In your code you are trying to get absolute position of the page according to the application that is why you are getting 0 for offset values.

Answer (score 1):

Get a reference for TextBox like so, don't use "this." "this" in this case is a totally different object:

```
    private void txt1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox t = sender as TextBox;
        GeneralTransform gt ...
    }
```

Comment: Yes that is the same as my solution. The only difference is you take the reference of the textbox from the event arguments "sender", however you don't need to do that because you already have reference to it from your codebehind using its name. The idea was that instead of using "this" you need to use the reference to your textbox.

Comment: Your solution would not work if the TextBox is in the DataTemplate inside a ListBox.

Comment: I see, I thought that the part after update in the question was the part that revolutionkpi added, not you.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted all of my textboxes to go to the right edge (minus 20). They are all aligned horizontally on the left.

I enabled the page SizeChanged event handler then added:

```
        private void Page_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            GeneralTransform gt = tbSvcMsgOut.TransformToVisual(this);
            Point offset = gt.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
            double controlTop = offset.Y;
            double controlLeft = offset.X;
            double newWidth =  e.NewSize.Width - controlLeft - 20;
            if (newWidth > tbSvcMsgOut.MinWidth)
            {
                tbSvcMsgOut.Width = newWidth;
                tbDeviceMsgIn.Width = newWidth;
                tbSvcMsgIn.Width = newWidth;
                tbDeiceMsgOut.Width = newWidth;
            }
        }
```

This works fine for me, :)